# Split a long form into rows but with duplicates merged as a string delimited with ";"?

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

Suppose I have a dataframe that I want to split into rows.

```
temp = data.frame ( group=c('a','b','c'), fruits = c('apple', 'orange', 'none'), days=c('mon','tues','wed') )
reshape2::dcast(temp , days ~ group, value.var=c ( "fruits") )
  days     a      b    c
1  mon apple   <NA> <NA>
2 tues  <NA> orange <NA>
3  wed  <NA>   <NA> none
```

This works fine, however when I add a duplicated row as such.

```
temp = rbind ( temp, c('a','orange','mon')  )
```

the casting would failed and only show the total.  What I really want is something like this.

```
 days     a      b    c
1  mon apple;orange   <NA> <NA>
2 tues  <NA> orange <NA>
3  wed  <NA>   <NA> none
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `tidyverse` solution. You can aggregate your data using `paste0()` to get a proper structure in order to transform to wide format:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
temp %>%
  group_by(group,days) %>%
  summarise(fruits=paste0(fruits,collapse = ';')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group,values_from=fruits)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  days  a            b      c    
  <chr> <chr>        <chr>  <chr>
1 mon   apple;orange NA     NA   
2 tues  NA           orange NA   
3 wed   NA           NA     none
```

Comment: perfect thank you! I was also using a two step solutions first by collapsing with paste but your solution is much cleaner.